# WiFi equipment for Gigabit link

Tags: wifi, router, switch, network-adapter

quI'm trying to setup a gigabits wifi:
- around 20+ clients, but around 4 require a actual gigabit links.
- Clients are in a 15meter range 49 (feet?)

I was dealing with a non-pro configuration at the moment :
NETGEAR Orbi Ultimate Whole Home Mesh Wi-Fi System (Router + 2 Satellite Extenders), (6000 sq ft Coverage)AC3000 (RBK53)

The issue with this, (not to mention the leak of VLAN and etc) is the speed...

I did some iPerf and even an ethernet link from the router > to the Orbi AP, the link is between 500/680Mb/s only (so not gonna even mention WiFi speed).

I was thinking : EdgeRouter 12 + 
Ubiquiti UAP-AC-HD * 2

or I read some post mentioning this setup :

UAP-AC-HD * 2
1 switch (perhaps a unifi-switch-8)
UBIQUITI Networks Unifi Security Gateway

Although I read some review saying that the DPI/IPS from the security gateway does reduce the speed a lot.

What should I go for?